# How to block gmap when there is no internet connection

Tags: google-maps, jsf, primefaces

I'm using the PrimeFaces component `gmap`, to be able to use Google Maps service. It works fine for me, but I have an issue. When there is no internet connection, my user interface totally get blocked. Is there any way to solve this problem, by not rendering the `gmap` in case no internet connection? This is my code:

```
<p:gmap id="geoGmap" widgetVar="geoMap" center="#{managedBean.centerGeoMap}" zoom="15" type="ROADMAP" model="#{managedBean.geoModel}" style="width:1000px;height:500px" streetView="false" disableDefaultUI="true"  >
    <p:ajax event="geocode" listener="#{managedBean.onGeocode}" update="@this" />
</p:gmap>
```

And here is the script to import it:

```
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

Comment: How do your users access your application? Is it on an intranet?

Comment: the users access the application via enterprise network

Comment: Is your application hosted from the same network?

Comment: i think it is hosted in the same network

Comment: currently my application is deployed locally on glassfish

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *When there is no internet connection, my user interface totally get blocked*

This is caused by a JavaScript error. You can see it when you check the JavaScript console in browser's developer toolset. Press F12 in Chrome/FF23+/IE9+ to see it.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
```

In Chrome, you can unfold a stack trace. When you click the first line, it refers to the script generated by `<p:gmap>` in HTML source as shown below (whitespace manually inserted for readability):

```
<script id="geoGmap_s" type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        PrimeFaces.cw('GMap', 'geoMap', {
            id: 'geoGmap',
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, // <-- Here,
            center:new google.maps.LatLng(...),       // <-- and here.
            ...
        });
    });
</script>
```

Look, this inline script is trying to dereference the variable `google` which is supposed to be put in the window scope by the Google Maps API JavaScript file. However, when there's no internet connection, then that Google Maps API JavaScript file fails to load and hence there will be no `google` variable in the window scope and therefore this `<p:gmap>`-generated script will throw an error saying that the variable `google` is undefined.

When there's an unhandled error in JavaScript context, then the JavaScript execution will come to a total halt. In other words, the remaining scripts, such as those for other PrimeFaces user interface components whose functionality heavily depend on JavaScript, won't at all be executed. That explains your observation of "my user interface totally get blocked".

Technically, the solution is rather straight forward: the `<p:gmap>` should not try to execute that script when the variable `google` is not in the window scope.

In order to achieve that, you need to extend the renderer of `<p:gmap>`, the [`GMapRenderer`](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/6_0/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/gmap/GMapRenderer.java), to write an `if (window.google)` directly after starting of the script:

```
public class YourGMapRenderer extends GMapRenderer {

    @Override
    protected void startScript(ResponseWriter writer, String clientId) throws IOException {
        super.startScript(writer, clientId);
        writer.write("if(window.google)");
    }

}
```

In order to get it to run, register it as below in `faces-config.xml` where the `<renderer-class>` represents the FQN of your extended renderer class:

```
<render-kit>
    <renderer>
        <component-family>org.primefaces.component</component-family>
        <renderer-type>org.primefaces.component.GMapRenderer</renderer-type>
        <renderer-class>com.example.YourGMapRenderer</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
</render-kit>
```

Once installed, it will change the rendered script as below:

```
<script id="geoGmap_s" type="text/javascript">
    if (window.google) $(function() {
        PrimeFaces.cw('GMap', 'geoMap', {
            ...
        });
    });
</script>
```

In other words, the function will only be invoked when `window.google` is truthy, i.e. when the `google` variable is available in JavaScript's window scope.

That should avoid the JS error and let the JS execution continue.